# Visual Studio 2017 - how to make code formatting follow reactjs projects eslint rules?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, eslint

Is there a way to make VS2017 code formatting (ctrl-k-d) to use projects local eslinter rules in a reactjs project that uses `js` files (not `jsx`).

Comment: Just install the ESLint extension?

Comment: yeah, that would be cool:) i have installed VisualLinter and it throws linting errors as expected but code format doesnt follow projects linting rules.

Comment: What do you mean "code format doesnt follow projects linting rules". As in the linter IS working, but it's using default parameters and not using your `.eslintrc` parameters?

Comment: Do you have the eslint npm module installed in your project folder? Or installed globally?

Comment: for example, there are identation rules. if i write code with wrong identation (according to linter) then i get linter errors as expected. if i manually make identation to follow linter rules - all is ok. but if i press ctrl-k-d, it sets identation completely unrelated to linter rules. so, linting itself does work but code formatting using ctrl-k-d is not following linter rules. not sure how to explain it bettter.

Comment: eslint npm module is not installed in project. its global.

Comment: Some news? I am passing through same problems...